# Legality of physically publishing Stack Exchange content verbatim

Tags: discussion, copyright-infringement

This was brought to my awareness on a Facebook D&D forum.

http://www.barnesandnoble.com/w/dungeons-dragons-5th-edition-george-a-duckett/1123824843?ean=9781533294517

This fellow, George Duckett, has published 378+ books by gathering the content from Stack Exchange, dumping it into some semblance of a document, and then selling Stack Exchange content on Amazon and Barnes and Noble to profit directly.

Comment: Related: [Proper attribution of Stack Exchange content in a printed publication](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/288561/307988)

Comment: Also related: "this fellow" is an [active user of Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/281469), so you're talking about someone present here.